# Array as Ajax request data with DataTables

Tags: arrays, ajax, parameters, datatables, request

I want to send the id's from the selected rows to an API with [DataTables Ajax option](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax) but no matter what I try, I can't send the id's as an array.

The code below is an example of what I've tried. It will result in the following url:

[getStatistics.php?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3&ids=4](http://getStatistics.php?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3&ids=4)

What I really want is this:

[getStatistics.php?ids=1,2,3,4](http://getStatistics.php?ids=1,2,3,4)

```
var selectedIds = [1,2,3,4];

"ajax": {
    "url": "getStatistics.php",
    "traditional": true,
    "data": {"ids": selectedIds}
}
```

I don't know if the problem is tied to DataTables but I really need help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join?v=example) to convert array to comma-separated string.

For example:

```
"ajax": {
    "url": "getStatistics.php",
    "traditional": true,
    "data": { "ids": selectedIds.join(',') }
}
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/v6d0yhqo/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much!